# Pull messages from Oracle AQ using node js

Tags: node.js, oracle, queue

How do I pull/push messages from/to Oracle Advanced Queue(OAQ) using nodejs ?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/introducing-node-oracledb-a-nodejs-driver-for-oracle-database

Comment: Until node-oracledb has a native AQ API, you can call the PL/SQL AQ API.  Check out the AQ example on p221 of Oracle's free book on PHP at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html.  This shows an example of setting up the PL/SQL packages.  Rewriting the PHP code that calls the PL/SQL to node-oracledb syntax is straightforward,

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Native support for AQ queues is now available in node-oracledb 4.0.  The API is discussed in the documentation https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#aq

Comment: Is there a way to read messages from the Oracle AQ using node.js or Spring etc instead of fetching from databases ?After fetching the messages from Oracle AQ queue,we need to perform few business logics etc and then place the transformed message again on the queue

Comment: If you want a driver that has native AQ API's, use Python cx_Oracle.  There is still going to be round-trip traffic between the application and the DB in any solution.